# How is the device able to receive notifications even though SBNotificationHub.RegisterNativeAsync() is never called?

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

This code results in the device receiving a test notification, but there's no call to `RegisterNativeAsync` unless there's an error. Thus, how does the hub know about the device?

```
 [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        SBNotificationHub Hub { get; set; }

        public const string ConnectionString = "Endpoint=xxx";

        public const string NotificationHubPath = "xxx";

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            // Create a new notification hub with the connection string and hub path
            Hub = new SBNotificationHub(ConnectionString, NotificationHubPath);



            // Unregister any previous instances using the device token
            Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken, (error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    // Error unregistering
                    return;
                }

                // Register this device with the notification hub
                Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, null, (registerError) =>
                {
                    if (registerError != null)
                    {
                        // Error registering
                    }
                });
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: _"but there's no call to `RegisterNativeAsync` unless there's an error."_ - really? I see just the contrary, it's called if there was _no_ error calling `UnregisterAllAsync`.

Comment: Yes, I think you may have a point.

Comment: Although haven’t yet hit a breaknpoint.

Comment: Anyway, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhub.unregisterallasync.aspx , the method has only one parameter, so I've no idea how that code compiles at all. This _could_ be (yet another) syntactic sugar of which C# is chock-full yet I failed to find anything similar. Where did you get this code?

Comment: I'm a big fan of C#'s syntactic sugar. It's a Xamarin API. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS/

Comment: I see. This version of `UnregisterAllAsync` does have a 2nd parameter. That was a critical piece of information!

Answer (score 0):

According to [RegisteredForRemoteNotifications - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.RegisteredForRemoteNotifications/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSData/), **this method has nothing to do with registering itself**.<sup>1</sup> As far a I can tell from [RegisteredForRemoteNotifications never triggered — Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26514/registeredforremotenotifications-never-triggered), applications are supposed to override it, and it serves as a handler that is invoked **after** the user allows the application to receive push notifications.

**In fact, the code you've given is *your* code, not library's.**

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>And examining the source code of `UnregisterAllAsync` in [ILSpy](http://www.ilspy.net) decompilation of `Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS.dll` confirms as such.</sub>